# Cooling a Machine with Tubes, Are My Calculations Reasonable?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have been tasked with estimating what velocity I need coolant to pass through some tubes that will be used to cool hot machinery. If you could check over my calculations and see if they are reasonable I would appreciate it. I assume that because these tubes will be very small that the flow will be steady and laminar. I neglect the temperature of the tube itself to make the calculation simpler, and assume that the heat flow rate is reasonably constant.

Take the heat transfer equation: $$H = -kA\frac{dT}{dr}$$ I integrated over the inside temp and outside temp of the tube (what I approximate as the temp of the coolant and temp of the machinery respectively) and over the two radii to get $$H = \frac{2\pi kD(T_{c}-T_{m})}{ln(\frac{r_2}{r_1})}$$ where $T_M$ and $T_c$ are the temperature of the machinery and coolant, and $r_2$ and $r_1$ are the outside and inside radii of the pipe respectively (and $D$ is the length of the pipe). Now lets say that because the heat transfer rate is constant I can set it as $H=\frac{Q}{t}$ where $Q$ is the amount of heat transferred to the coolant while it is inside the machine and $t$ is the time that it is inside the machine. I multiply both sides by $t$ and make use of the face that $D$ (the length of the pipe) divided by $t$ is the velocity of the coolant and get: $$Q = \frac{2\pi kD^2(T_{c}-T_{m})}{vln(\frac{r_2}{r_1})}$$ Solving for the velocity of the coolant, $$v = \frac{2\pi kD^2(T_{c}-T_{m})}{Qln(\frac{r_2}{r_1})}$$ Now we must find the heat that will be transferred to the coolant while in the machine. We know $Q=mc*(T_f-T_i))$ and because we need the heat transfer rate to be constant I will assume that we need our velocity to be large and thus the coolant to not stay in the machine very long and thus not change temperature too much. Plugging this into the equation for velocity we get: $$v = \frac{2\pi kD^2(T_{c}-T_{m})}{((\rho \pi r_1^2D)c(T_f-T_i))ln(\frac{r_2}{r_1})}$$ $$v = \frac{2kD(T_{c}-T_{m})}{((\rho r_1^2)c(T_f-T_i))ln(\frac{r_2}{r_1})}$$ And there it is. I would now assume I suppose that my $T_c$ is the average temp that the coolant will reach while in the machine and specify a reasonable range of temperatures $T_f$ and $T_i$ such that the coolant, and thus the machine, stays cool throughout the coolant's journey through the machine. Obviously a ton of assumptions and approximations, but do you think that this is reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up some concepts and starting from a false assumption: if heat transfer takes place $T_c$, $T_m$ or both **must** change in time. Here I'll be assuming $T_m$ is constant. We'll use lumped thermal analysis.

[image: Cooling a nmachine]

$$\frac{dq}{dt}=udA(T(x)-T_m)\tag{1}$$
Where $T(x)$ is the temperature of the coolant at a point $x$ of the pipe, $u$ is the overall heat transfer coefficient and $dA$:

$$dA=2\pi r_2dx\tag{2}$$
$$dq=-dmc_pdT(x)$$
Where $c_p$ is the specific heat capacity of the coolant. Dividing both sides by $dt$:
$$\frac{dq}{dt}=-\dot{m}c_pdT(x)\tag{3}$$
$\dot{m}$ is the mass throughput of coolant.
With $(1)=(3)$ and $(2)$:
$$2u\pi r_2(T(x)-T_m)dx=-\dot{m}c_pdT$$
$$-\frac{2u\pi r_2}{\dot{m}c_p}dx=\frac{dT(x)}{T(x)-T_m}\tag{4}$$
For ease of notation:
$$\alpha=\frac{2u\pi r_2}{\dot{m}c_p}$$
$$\int_0^x-\alpha dx=\int_{T_0}^{T_1}\frac{dT(x)}{T(x)-T_m}$$
With $T_0$ the initial temperature of the coolant on entering the pipe.

$$-\alpha x=\ln\Big[\frac{T(x)-T_m}{T_0-T_m}\Big]$$
$$\frac{T(x)-T_m}{T_0-T_m}=e^{-\alpha x}\implies T(x)-T_m=(T_0-T_m)e^{-\alpha x}\tag{5}$$
Now insert $(5)$ into $(1)$ with $(2)$:
$$\frac{dq}{dt}=2u\pi r_2(T_0-T_m)e^{-\alpha x}dx$$
What you're interesting in is how much heat is being withdrawn from the machine per unit of time: $P$. With $L$ the total length of pipe:
$$P=\int_0^L\frac{dq}{dt}=2u\pi r_2\int_0^L(T_0-T_m)e^{-\alpha x}dx\tag{6}$$
I'll leave that integration to you.

Now we still need to know the **heat transfer coefficient** $u$. As long as the pipe is not too thick we can use the following approximation:

$$\frac1u \approx\frac{1}{h_1}+\frac{r_2-r_1}{k}+\frac{1}{h_2}$$
Where $h_1$ is the convection coefficient for coolant to pipe, $k$ the heat conductivity of the pipe and $h_2$ the convection coefficient for pipe to machine (if that contact is intimate metal to metal then $h_2=+\infty$).

Comment: One more question, after I find P can I use $P=\frac{Q}{t}=\frac{(mc(T_f-T_o)}{t}=\frac{((\rho*(\pi*r_1^2*L))c(T_f-T_i)}{t}$ to get at the velocity or is that wrong as well?

Comment: $(6)$ integrates to $P=-\dot{m}c_p(T_0-T_m)(e^{-\alpha L}-1)$, from there calculate $\dot{m}$. That's the coolant mass throughput needed to achieve $P$.

Comment: Ooopsie. There was an error in $dA$, Should be $dA=2\pi r_2$. All correct now.

Comment: That's already been corrected.

Comment: No, I corrected that too. Maybe you should reload the page?

Comment: Very strange. To me it says $\frac{dq}{dt}=2u\pi r_2(T(x)-T_m)e^{-\alpha x}$. ???

Comment: Yes, my bad. There was a $dx$ missing too. It;s getting very late here!